# Finding the inverse Laplace transform of a physics related problem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform, fractions

I'm trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of:

$$\frac{as+b}{s(cs+d)+g}\tag1$$

First of all I can expand the fraction:

$$\frac{as+b}{s(cs+d)+g}=a\cdot\frac{
s}{s(cs+d)+g}+b\cdot\frac{1}{s(cs+d)+g}\tag2$$

And from now on I've no idea

---

Background: this inverse Laplace transform is important in solving a second order DE.

Comment: $$\frac{e^{-\frac{t \left(\sqrt{d^2-4 c g}+d\right)}{2 c}} \left(a \left(\left(\sqrt{d^2-4 c g}-d\right) e^{\frac{t \sqrt{d^2-4 c g}}{c}}+\sqrt{d^2-4 c g}\right)+a d+2 b c \left(e^{\frac{t \sqrt{d^2-4 c g}}{c}}-1\right)\right)}{2 c \sqrt{d^2-4 c g}}$$

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition that you want is
$$\frac {s - s_0} {(s - s_1) (s - s_2)} =
\frac {s_1 - s_0} {(s_1 - s_2) (s - s_1)} -
 \frac {s_2 - s_0} {(s_1 - s_2) (s - s_2)}.$$
Then the problem reduces to finding the inverse transform of $1/(s - \text{const})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$s(cs+d)+g=cs^2+ds+g=\left(\sqrt{c}s+\frac{d}{2\sqrt{c}}\right)^2+\left(g-\frac{d^2}{4c}\right)$$
so we can say:
$$\frac{as+b}{s(cs+d)+g}=\frac{as+b}{\left(\sqrt{c}s+\frac{d}{2\sqrt{c}}\right)^2+\left(g-\frac{d^2}{4c}\right)}$$
or we could rewrite it as:
$$\frac{as+b}{\left(\sqrt{c}s+\frac{d}{2\sqrt{c}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{d^2}{4c}-g\right)}=\frac{as+b}{\left(\sqrt{c}s+\frac{d}{2\sqrt{c}}\right)^2-\sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4c}-g}^2}$$

You could try and make a substitution from this i.e. let $u=\sqrt{c}s+\frac{d}{2\sqrt{c}}$ and then use partial fractions, calculate the inverse Laplace transform **then** backsubstitute